# XNA 2D Camera doesnt keep sprite centered

Tags: c#, xna, 2d, xna-4.0

I've been working on a kind of spaceship game in which you take a lander and take off from the ground and fly up as high as you can get until you come crashing down.  The problem I've been running into is that the camera that I've tried to implement doesn't keep the lander in the center, the lander eventually gets faster then the camera and goes off screen.  I don't understand why and I've tried everything to make it work.  I created a test case in which I used the camera on a simple program where a sprite moved in four directions.  That one worked fine, but when I implemented the camera on my main game, it doesn't work correctly.  Any help would be appreciated.

This is the camera class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;

namespace WindowsGame4.Main
{
  class Camera
  {
    public Matrix transform;
    Viewport view;
    Vector2 centre;

    public Camera(Viewport newView)
    {
        view = newView;
    }

    public void Update(GameTime gameTime, Game1 lander, Lander _lander)
    {
        centre = new Vector2(_lander.Position.X + (lander.lander.Width / 2) - 455, _lander.Position.Y + (lander.lander.Height/2)-910);
        transform = Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(-centre.X - _lander.Velocity.X, -centre.Y - _lander.Velocity.Y, 0));
    }
    }
    }
```

This is the main update method in Game1:

```
    // Creates the handler to allow the use of the keyboard inputs
            KeyboardState keyboard = Keyboard.GetState(); 
            // Sets up the launch position to allow for scoring and height determining
            startPos = 700f;                
            // Mainly for debug, allows for leaving the game whenever desired
            if (keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
            {
                Exit();
            }

       // The logic for the thruster, checks for if the space key is down and if 
       // the lander has any fuel remaining.  If there is no fuel the thrusters
       // will not work.
        if (keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space) && !empty)
        {
            _lander.Accelerate(_thruster.GetAcceleration(), gameTime.ElapsedGameTime);               
            // Turns on the thruster
            _thruster.Active = true; 
            // Tells the program that the lander has taken off, allowing the gravity to kick in
            landed = false;
            // Keeps track of the amount of fuel you have
            if (_lander.Fuel > 0)
            {
                // Subtracts 1 from the fuel for every second that the 'SPACE' key is down
                _lander.Fuel--;
            }
            else if (_lander.Fuel <= 0)
            {
                empty = true;
                endPos = _lander.Position.Y;
            }
        }
        if (keyboard.IsKeyUp(Keys.Space) || empty)
        {
            // Turns off the thruster as long as the player is not pressing 'SPACE'
            _thruster.Active = false; 
        }

        // This is the logic structure for the landing portion of the game, it sets up a 
        // level area in which the player can land on, which in turn then checks the Position.X value
        // to see how many points to give based on their close proximity to the landing site.  
        // ** Could possibly add depth or different levels based on location, like landing on a mountain
        // ** Or landing in the bottom of a crater
        if (_lander.Position.Y >= 800)
        {
            landed = true;
            // If you have died or Failed a mission 3 times then the game is over
            if (_lander.Lives == 1)
            {
                currentGameState = GameState.GameOver;                    
            }
            // As long as you have a life left the game will continue
            // This logic also is only applied if the player has landed on the ground
            // ** Add a rotational fixer as to make the lander stand straight up as opposed to the way its oriented
            // ** Upon landing
            else if (_lander.Lives > 0)
            {                   
                    // Sets the landers position to the current position that its landed at, thus stopping the gravity
                    // Resets the velocity, thus making sure it doesnt continue to fall
                    _lander.Position = new Vector2(_lander.Position.X, _lander.Position.Y);
                    _lander.Velocity = new Vector2();

                    // Sets up the first landing site, this particular one is the highset value landing site is almost right 
                    // On top of the flag that is placed to indicate where to land.
                    // *** Will Not Use In Final Version, Will Substitue With Logic For Height And Cash Gained ***
                    if ((_lander.Position.X >= 600 && _lander.Position.X <= 650) || (_lander.Position.X <= 600 && _lander.Position.X >= 550))
                    {   
                        // *** Will be implemented to display a "YOU HAVE FAILED THE MISSION" screen. ***
                        failure = false;
                        // This is for debugging purposes only, will change to be automatic once all functions are complete
                        if (keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.Enter))
                        {
                            // (1) -- Resets the position of the lander back to its original position and Velocity
                            // (2) -- Add 150 points to the score based on the location that the lander set down at
                            // (3) -- Continues on to the next level

                            _lander.Position = new Vector2(graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth / 2, 100); // (1)
                            _lander.Velocity = new Vector2(); // (1)
                            _lander.Score += 150; // (2)
                            currentGameState = GameState.Level2; // (3) 
                        }
                    }
                    // Sets up the second landing site, this particular one is the second highest value landing site that is 
                    // A large circle surrounding the landing site above
                    else if ((_lander.Position.X >= 651 && _lander.Position.X <= 750 ) || (_lander.Position.X <= 549 && _lander.Position.X >= 450))
                    {
                        // *** Will be implemented to display a "YOU HAVE FAILED THE MISSION" screen. ***
                        failure = false;
                        // This is for debugging purposes only, will change to be automatic once all functions are complete
                        if (keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.Enter))
                        {
                            // (1) -- Resets the position of the lander back to its original position and Velocity
                            // (2) -- Add 50 points to the score based on the location that the lander set down at
                            // (3) -- Continues on to the next level

                            _lander.Position = new Vector2(graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth / 2, 100); // (1)
                            _lander.Velocity = new Vector2(); // (1)
                            _lander.Score += 50; // (2)
                            currentGameState = GameState.Level2; // (3)
                        }                            
                    }
                    // Sets up the final landing site, this particular one is the failing portion of the map that is 
                    // A large area that encompasses the rest of the map.
                    else if ((_lander.Position.X >= 751 && _lander.Position.X <= 850) || (_lander.Position.X <= 449 && _lander.Position.X >= 0))
                    {
                        // You get no points so it does not only need to done once, it can be done as many times as needed
                        // And it will not change the data
                        _lander.Score = 0;
                        // *** Will be implemented to display a "YOU HAVE FAILED THE MISSION" screen. ***
                        failure = true;
                        // This is for debugging purposes only, will change to be automatic once all functions are complete
                        if (keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.Enter))
                        {
                            // (1) -- Resets the position of the lander back to its original position and Velocity
                            // (2) -- Takes away one of your lives as a result of the players failure to land correctly

                            _lander.Position = new Vector2(graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth / 2, 100); // (1)
                            _lander.Velocity = new Vector2(); // (1)
                            _lander.Lives--; // (2)
                        }                              

                    }
                    // This is just a loop that gives a visual representation of refueling before the next level begins.
                    for (double i = _lander.Fuel; i < 500; i++)
                    {
                        _lander.Fuel += .05;                            
                    }
                }
            }
        // A very simple call to the Gravity and Lander classes that simulates gravity as long as the 
        // lander has not landed            
        else if (!landed)
        {
           _lander.Accelerate(_gravity.GetAcceleration(), gameTime.ElapsedGameTime);               
        }

        // Moves the lander according to gravity calculated by the lander class
        _lander.DoMovement(gameTime.ElapsedGameTime);

        // Calculates the height achieved based off of starting height and ending height
        height = startPos - endPos;
        // This will rotate the lander when the keys are pressed down
        // They will also check to make sure if it is landed or not
        // If it's landed then it will not allow the lander to rotate.
        if (keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left) && landed == false)
        {
            // (1) -- This will also change the angle of rotation for the thruster as to all for movement in 
            // That specific direction. 
            // Example: if you rotate to the left and turn on the thrusters you will starting moving
            // to the left

            rotation -= 0.1f;
            _lander.Rotation = rotation;
            _thruster.Rotation = rotation; // (1)
        }
        if (keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right) && landed == false)
        {
            // (1) -- This will also change the angle of rotation for the thruster as to all for movement in that specific direction.
            // (2) -- This will also change the angle of rotation for the lander as to all for movement in that specific direction.
            // Example: if you rotate to the right and turn on the thrusters you will starting moving
            // to the right

            rotation += 0.1f;
            _lander.Rotation = rotation; // (2)
            _thruster.Rotation = rotation;   // (1)
        }

        // Calls the camera class to allow the screen to move with the player
        camera.Update(gameTime, this, _lander);
```

If you guys need more code I can upload anything else you guys need

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to use a translation for a 2D camera? It's a very complicated way for something that can be done a lot simpler. A 2D camera in my opinion should just be a vector corresponding to the upper-left corner of the camera's viewport. Then just subtract the camera vector from any sprite position and it will move along with the camera.

So in your case, just set the camera vector to be at the center point minus half of the screen width and height:

```
Camera = SpriteCenter - new Vector2(GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width / 2, GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height / 2);
```

For every drawing call, subtract the Camera vector from the actual position of a sprite.
And there you go, your sprite will always be centered.

If you are doing something special that doesn't allow this to function, then I am unable to understand your actual question. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with @Sarkilas, I think using a transformation will simplify your code, not needing to specify the camera each time.

You can use this code as a base for position, origin, zoom, and rotation.

```
return Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(-Position, 0.0f)) *
       Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(-Origin, 0.0f)) *
       Matrix.CreateRotationZ(Rotation) *
       Matrix.CreateScale(Zoom, Zoom, 1) *
       Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(Origin, 0.0f));
```

The issue is that the lander is not your origin, it should be your position, while the origin should be half of your viewport size like so

```
Position = lander.Position;
Origin = new Vector2(view.Width / 2, view.Height / 2);
```

You will probably have to add half your lander position back to the origin or position if it looks a bit off.